# Objective C: how to get an integer from uitextfield to work as a timer

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, timer, uitextfield

I'm creating my first app with Objective C, one function with let the user to provide an amount (in numbers) with 2 decimal places into a UITextField. I would like that to be processed using a UIButton to appear in a UILabel which runs according to a timer.

I.E. if the user inputs 5.60 into the UITextField, when the UIButton is pressed, this amount should transfer to the UILabel which acts as timer and counts to 5.60 every 60 seconds.

The counter should go up by 0.01 to reach 5.60 in 60 seconds.

This is all on one ViewController.

Thanks in advance if anyone sees this and has the time to help!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show us your code and what exact problem are you expiriencing

Comment: The way to go about this would be to first get the UITextField contents, as an integer:

*Pseudo Code:*

    @property (nonatomic) NSUInteger totalTime;

   self.totalTime = (NSUInteger)textField.text;

Then, set your timer up from there.

Comment: So far I have a timer(UILabel1) that runs as a stop watch. Below that I have another timer (UILabel2) which I want to run so it reaches the number the user provided when the first timer hits 60 seconds. Every time UILabel2 reaches it's target I have a count(UILabel3) which adds 1 to it's count. UILabel2 is reset and starts counting until it reaches the target again and so forth. I have the UILabel1 coded to run as a clock. I have UILabel3 to add 1 and I have the UIlabel2 resetting itself when it reaches the target, but at the mo the target is just an amount I have given it in the coding.

Comment: UILabel2 - 

-(void)Timer2:(NSTimer *)sender {
    
    value1++;
    if (value1 == 100)
    {
        value1 = 0;
        value2++;
        
    }
    
    Timer2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02i.%02i", value2, value1];
    
    if (value2 == 0 && value1 >= 60){

        [self Count];
        value2 = 0;
        value1 = 0;
        
    }
    
}

Comment: UILabel1 - -(void)Timer1:(NSTimer *)Timer{ Seconds++; if (Seconds == 60) { Seconds = 0; Minutes++; if (Minutes == 60) { Minutes = 0; Hours++; } } HoursWorked.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %02i:%02i:%02i",Hours,Minutes,Seconds]; } –